# How can I get typeorm to work with ionic 5/6?

Tags: ionic-framework, typeorm, ionic5

I guess my question is two-fold.

We use SQLite for our native apps (with offline first capabilities) but I've been looking to find an alternative that handles migrations well. I looked into https://typeorm.io/ which seemed interesting but I haven't found a tutorial that isn't at least a couple of years old. The [official example](https://github.com/typeorm/ionic-example) is 5 years old. Other [tutorials](https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-angular-typeorm-custom-webpack-configuration/) are quite old too and after setting up following the instructions, I had more errors than before so that didn't work. Now to get into the questions.

1. Is there anyone out there using ionic 5/6 with TypeOrm with data persistence on the native devices? If yes, do share a link with instructions on how to set up.
2. If you are using SQLite, how do you manage the schema changes with that?